# Facebook scores blocked by "only me" visibility

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, privacy, leaderboard

I have a game with highscores and I use the fb-score api to generate a friend leaderboard. One problem though ... to save a score for a fb-user, the app has to "post data for the user" ... in this case, the score-data. But the user can choose to mark this "posting" permission as visible for "only me" instead of global or friends. Which is something a lot of users will do since it sounds like something that would aid their privacy.

That however means that the score of ... lets say USER A ... will never show up in the leaderboard of a friend (USER B), since its something the app has posted for USER A, and this is now unintentionally invisible for all of his friends. But USER A has not really a way to find out about this mistake, and that none of his friends can see his awesome highscore, since he can see his highscore without problems.

That brings me to the question: How can I work around or even approach that problem in any way? Is there a way to get score data for a user even when he marked "app posts" as visible for only himself? Is that an accesstoken thing, user or app? Or could I somehow check if the user has done such a thing and alert him to change the post-permission visibility? As far as I know i can only check if a permission is given or not, but not its visibility. I would really want to work past setting up a server of my own to handle that data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately this seems to be the designed behaviour. User A has stated via his visibility preferences that he only wants to share information about this game (such as his score) with himself, therefore it makes sense that other users cannot see his score.
To achieve your goal, an additional database is necessary.