# Facebook iOs Leaderboards

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish, leaderboard

I would like to use the Facebook Scores API to make a social leaderboard for my iOS game.
From the documentation, I saw that it would require to request a publish permission so that I could post scores. The thing is that I don't want to publish to the player's wall (I simply think it's invasive), I just want to use the API backend to store the score, but everything I saw involved posting to the user's wall in order to write the score on the backend.

How should I proceed to only write the score without posting it into facebook?
If this thing exists, can I avoid requiring the publish permission?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the work you have done so far. Otherwise this looks like you are asking for code.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use the Score API as intended, the user will have the option of choosing whether to give your app the visibility permissions like "private, friends, public, etc".  That lets the user decide what is invasive rather than you deciding for them.

Here is a related stackoverflow question with the opposite question, showing how users have control over what is shared with the API:
[Facebook scores blocked by "only me" visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071117/facebook-scores-blocked-by-only-me-visibility?rq=1)

Comment: Thks Henry, the thing is that when prompting for the publish permission it is done in a different dialog popup than the public profile and friends persmission. This double popup wouldn't be sthg I am looking foward to, nor posting to the user's wall when I simply want to store his score. Anyway I think the best solution would be to have a login in facebook and a custom backend for storing the scores. Thks for your response.

Comment: Well if you don't want social leaderboards, then the facebook score api is the wrong thing to be using.  If you really wanted to use facebook as a personal data store you can use User Owned Objects: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#objectapi-appanduserobjects.  However, since you simply want to store data, I would use Parse.com.  It's easier to use and you'll get Facebook and Twitter sign in for free.

Comment: thks Henry, I'l try that out and see what happens!